# Jquery Current Date Less Than X, Change At Specific Time (Instead of Midnight)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I'm building a carousel that shows featured content specific to Friday nights. Below you can see on load I trigger a click to the upcoming Friday night's content using new Date(). Accounts of course wants this content to change Friday night after the event is over at 9pm instead of midnight.

```
function loadFirstMovie(){
        $el.find(settings.children).each(function(i){
            var t = $(this)
            var currentDate = new Date() // get current date
            var itemDate = new Date(t.attr('date'))

            if (currentDate < itemDate){
                t.trigger("click");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can pass a time into new Date(), but NOT a specific day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var itemDate = new Date("2015-07-17T21:00:00");
//Creates a Date specific to 17th of July 2015, 9:00PM UTC
var year = 2015;
var month = 7;
var day = 17;
var hours = 21;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var milliseconds = 0;
var alternativeItemDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

You can use that to create a date with current year/month/day combination and the needed hours/minutes combination.